# Type error failing to be reported in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I have defined this type:

```js
export type RemoveFromWishlistFailureAction = {
  type: types.REMOVE_FROM_WISHLIST_FAILURE,
  error: Error
};
```

Elsewhere I have this code:

```js
const removeFailure: RemoveFromWishlistFailureAction = {
  type: types.REMOVE_FROM_WISHLIST_FAILURE
};
```

I expect there to be a Flow error because this object is missing an `error` property. There is no error.

Is there something wrong in my code, or in my understanding? Or elsewhere?

Comment: When I try it, it gives me an error. Maybe the type is somehow being imported as `any` or you otherwise aren't type checking those files. ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAShC2B7AbhAYgJ0fA6gSwGcALAG0ODQEM8SBXDCAQQGNg9EA7KAXigG8AUFCihIALigByGAFEAsgHkAajID6aGArmqcASQDKACQAyBgCrrGu4wFVZkgDRCoEDFgwSZbxBgEBfAG4BAWZOAmAoBiRUKhp6CAk4aPQsXEJScli6BhY2Th5+Z1EEqVlFFXVNbT0jU30LNCtbe38AoA))

Comment: i agree with @user11307804 that's not possible because error is not optional property of `RemoveFromWishlistFailureAction`.